# How to write a SQL server-side module (Stored Procedure) containing the dynamic SQL code to create documents?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2019

I have written a stored procedure containing dynamic SQL to create the documents of the specified format.
Whether the documents will be for the sales territories or salespersons will be determined at the run time as it is Dynamic SQL.

Documents for the sales territories:

```
{"TerritoryID":1,"TotalYearlySales":[2620944,5325813,6759501,3355403]},  
{"TerritoryID":2,"TotalYearlySales":[705672,3272240,2965567,876731]}
```

Documents for the salespersons:

```
{"SalesPersonID":274, "TotalYearlySales":[32568,516197,485881,201289]},     
{"SalesPersonID":275, "TotalYearlySales":[986298,3806298,4490942,1191828]}
```

The data in the documents is from AdventureWorks

```sql
create procedure dbo.TotalYearlySales
    @id nvarchar(30)
as
begin
    set @id = cast (@id as varchar(30))
    SELECT DISTINCT @id,
            JSON_QUERY('[' +
                STUFF(
                    (SELECT ',', rtrim(cast(SUM(TotalDue) as int))
                     FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH2
                     WHERE SOH1.@id = SOH2.@id 
                     AND SOH2.@id is not null
                     GROUP BY YEAR(SOH2.OrderDate)
                     ORDER BY YEAR(SOH2.OrderDate)
                     FOR XML PATH(''))
                , 1, 1, '')
            + ']') as TotalYearlySales
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH1
    GROUP BY cast (@id as varchar(30))
    ORDER BY cast (@id as varchar(30))
    FOR JSON AUTO;
end



    
declare @MyInput varchar(20);
set @MyInput= 'TerritoryID';
exec dbo.TotalYearlySales @MyInput;
```

This SP is not working as I can't pass @id, I am getting an error Incorrect syntax near '@id'. Please let me know how to write stored procedure with dynamic SQL statements.

I am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: Hi @Zhorov I am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: That's not dynamic sql. Dynamic sql is where you use code to build a ***Variable*** containing the static sql that you want to run, then execute it using `sp_executesql`.  I suggest reading about dynamic sql online and coming back to us.

Comment: If sales territories or salespersons are the only two possible options I recommend avoiding dynamic sql at all. Just use a plain `if` and two versions of the query.

Comment: BTW `A = B AND B is not null` should be `A = B`. null is never equal to null or whatever in `=` predicate.

Comment: I'm guessing that specific problem is with `SOH1.@id` - even if you have a column named `@id` (which in this case I would highly recommend renaming it).

Comment: And what's with all these unneeded casts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you need to build and execute a dynamic statement for a different grouping criteria (`TerritoryID` and `SalesPersonID`).

A possible approach, based on the attempt in the question, is the following stored procedure. Note, that starting from SQL Server 2017, you may use `STRING_AGG()` (instead of `FOR XML PATH`) for string aggregation:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TotalYearlySales
   @id sysname
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
   DECLARE @err int
   
   -- Dynamic statement
   SET @stm = 
      N'SELECT t.' + QUOTENAME(@id) + N', CONCAT(''['', STRING_AGG(t.TotalDue, '',''), '']'') AS TotalYearlySales ' +
      N'FROM ( ' +
         N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@id) + N', CONVERT(int, SUM(TotalDue)) AS TotalDue ' +
         N'FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader ' +
         N'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@id) + N' IS NOT NULL ' +
         N'GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(@id) + N', YEAR(OrderDate) ' +
      N') t ' +
      N'GROUP BY t.' + QUOTENAME(@id) + N' ' +
      N'FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER'

   -- Statement execution
   EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm, N' @id sysname', @id
   IF @err <> 0 BEGIN
      PRINT 'Error' 
   END
END
```

Execution:

```
DECLARE @MyInput sysname
SET @MyInput = N'TerritoryID';
EXEC dbo.TotalYearlySales @MyInput
```